# Is there a way to use a string in a variable's name when calling it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to programming so excuse my newbieness.
I'm using Visual Studio and in my program I have some variables in the Settings that are named by months;

```
JanuaryTotalAmount

JanuarySpentAmount

JanuaryGainedAmount

FebruaryTotalAmount

FebruarySpentAmount

FebruaryGainedAmount

ect...
```

So in my code when I assign them values I have:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.JanuaryTotalAmount += EnteredAmount;
Properties.Settings.Default.SpentAmount -= EnteredAmount;
```

They just add up values that are entered to get a total.

But I was trying to keep my code neater and was wondering if there was a way, based off of the month the user selects it will change the month name...

So

```
string month = txtBoxMonth.Text;

Properties.Settings.Default."month"TotalAmount += TotalAmount
```

That will then keep me from having to create a gigantic switch statement for every month.
I don't know if there is a way to do that or not, but any help is apprecieated.

Comment: What if you use `Dictionary` instead?

Comment: A dictionary and an enum with month names as a key.

Comment: What is the type of the amounts? is it `int`, `float`, `decimal`, ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mention that you are currently storing these values within your settings file.

You can access your settings via key:

```
public void GetMonthAmount(string month)
{
    string keyName = month + "TotalAmount";
    object monthData = Properties.Settings.Default[keyName];
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution that extends OP's code in a sensible way. However, as OP said he is new to programming, you should probably make that function do what is says (getters should not return `void`) and also cast the returned `object` to something more useful. Also a setter would be nice.

Comment: Thanks for all the help everyone. I was able to take this and modify it a bit to fit what I was doing and it works great. I am working with decimals as they are representing a money amount. So this is what I did...

============================================================================
    string key = month + "TotalAmount";
    decimal tempDec = Convert.ToDecimal(Properties.Setting.Default[key]);
    tempDec += Convert.ToDecimal("EnteredAmount");
    Properties.Settings.Default[key] = tempDec; // Sets property setting to the new amount
    Properties.Setting.Default.Save();

Answer (score 3):

As others have suggested, you could use a [`Dictionary<>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to store these values, with the key defined as an [enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/sbbt4032.aspx) that you also define. However, you cannot have a Settings value of this type directly, so you'd have to wrap it in a class:

```
public enum Month
{
    January,
    February,
    // and so on...
    December
}


public class Amounts
{
    public Amounts()
    {
        Months = new Dictionary<Month, int>();
    }

    public Dictionary<Month, int> Months { get; set; }
}
```

You can then add a value to your Settings for each of your *total*, *spent* and *gained* amounts, and access them like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.TotalAmounts = new Amounts();

Properties.Settings.Default.TotalAmounts.Months[Month.February] = 5;
```

Comment: Nice solution, but OP will probably need three dictionaries in Amounts: `TotalAmounts`, `SpentAmounts`, and `GainedAmounts`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the help, so this is what I was able to figure out with the provided answers. And yes I was wroking with decimals that are representing a money amount.

```
string key = month + "TotalAmount"; 
decimal tempDec = Convert.ToDecimal(Properties.Setting.Default[key]); // Creates a decimal to store the setting variable in using the key to access the correct setting variable
tempDec += Convert.ToDecimal("EnteredAmount"); // Adds the value of the Setting variable to the amount entered. 
Properties.Settings.Default[key] = tempDec; // Then sets the Setting variable to equal the temp variable.
Properties.Setting.Default.Save();
```

It works great and saves a lot of room!

Answer (score -1):

One option is try using [Reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt656691.aspx). Using reflection you can set/get property value by name using [SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and [GetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) functions.
You are new so you will need to read more in detail so posting some link for reference.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_reflection.htm
http://www.dotnetperls.com/reflection-property
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/axt1ctd9(v=vs.110).aspx

C# Code example(`obj` is object with property):

```
Type type = obj.GetType();
System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("JanuaryTotalAmount ");
propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, valueToSet, null);
```

So now create logic as per your need.